# Привязка триггера в стиле с помощью конкретного свойства

Tags: wpf

День добрый.
Есть стиль с триггером.

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="TextBoxMain">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="12,0,0,0"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisibility}" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

На форме есть несколько TextBox которые должны скрываться в зависимости от настроек ViewModel. Т.е.

```
<TextBox Text="Test1" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxMain}"/>
<TextBox Text="Test2" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxMain}"/>
```

Можно ли как то указать для триггера свойство привязки непосредственно при применении стиля в TextBox, который бы передавался DataTrigger в качестве объекта привязки. Что то вроде

```
<TextBox Text="Test1" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxMain, IsVisisbilityTest1}"/>
<TextBox Text="Test2" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxMain, IsVisisbilityTest2}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то параметризовать стиль, к сожалению, невозможно, но можно поступить следующим образом. У всех контролов имеется резервное свойство `Tag`, воспользуемся им:

```
<TextBox Text="Text 1" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxMain}" Tag="{Binding BoolProp1}"/>
<TextBox Text="Text 2" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxMain}" Tag="{Binding BoolProp2}"/>
<TextBox Text="Text 3" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxMain}" Tag="{Binding BoolProp3}"/>
```

А стиль перепишем следующим образом:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="TextBoxMain">
    ...
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Tag">
            <Trigger.Value>
                <s:Boolean>False</s:Boolean>
            </Trigger.Value>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Здесь `s` - пространство имен, определяемое следующим образом:

```
xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

---

Если у вас в разметке получается слишком много всевозможных констант наподобие `<s:Boolean>False</s:Boolean>`, то можно написать такое расширение разметки:

```
class ValueExtension<T> : MarkupExtension
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public ValueExtension() { }
    public ValueExtension(T value) => Value = value;
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => Value;
}

class BoolExtension : ValueExtension<bool>
{
    public BoolExtension() { }
    public BoolExtension(bool value) : base(value) { }
}
```

Тогда установка значения сократится до такого: `Value="{c:Bool False}"`