# Пользовательские MarkupExtension в качестве ключа словаря

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, xaml

К примеру, имеем такое расширение разметки:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Markup;
namespace CustomMarkupExtensions
{
    public class HelloExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        public HelloExtension() { }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return "Hello";
        }
    }
}
```

Код XAML. Пытаюсь использовать расширение в качестве ключа в ResourceDictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                    xmlns:ext="clr-namespace:CustomMarkupExtensions">

    <system:String x:Key="{ext:Hello}">Пример</system:String>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

При компиляции возникает ошибка:

```
(6,20): error MC3012: 
ключ словаря не может иметь тип "CustomMarkupExtensions.HelloExtension". 
Поддерживаются только типы String, TypeExtension и StaticExtension. Строка 6 позиция 20.
```

Хотя в [описании директивы x:Key](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/x-key-directive) указано, что расширения разметки использоваться могут. В чем дело?

Comment: Ого, интересный вопрос

Answer (score 3):

В справке всё указано верно: в `x:Key` можно использовать расширения разметки, но только два: `TypeExtension` и `StaticExtension`. Пользовательские расширения разметки не поддерживаются, кроме наследников `ResourceKey`. (Также `x:Key` может содержать произвольное значение, но указать его можно только с помощью одного из перечисленных выше расширений разметки.)

Это ограничение было снято в XAML 2009, вот только этот "стандарт" по сути не поддерживается.

В XAML 2006, который, похоже, с нами навсегда, можно пойти обходным путём: положить значение в статическое свойство, затем указать его через `x:Static`.

Comment: Обходной путь по сути мало что дает. Я могу сделать параметризированный MarkupExtension, например, [как здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/794510/218063) и использовать в качестве ключа число, enum или еще что-то. С `x:Static` мне придется делать потенциально бесконечное количество статических свойств

Comment: @Андрей Одно из двух: или словарь конечен и описан в замле, или бесконечен и описан в коде. В первом случае вы используете обходной путь, во втором случае он не нужен. Ну а енумы через х:статик и так достаются.

Comment: Хм, действительно достаются. Не знал, спасибо!

Comment: А как использовать XAML 2009? Как я понял, его в некоторых случаях можно использовать, но у меня не выходит. Можете привести рабочий пример для ResourceDictionary?

Comment: @Никита Новый XAML поддерживается только в некомпилированном виде, вы потеряете кучу функционала, я уж молчу про поддержку IDE, бросьте эту затею.